# is there a faster way to extract a large file tar in lz4 format?

Tags: compression, tar

I have a 7 TB file that is tared with lz4 compression.  It takes about 8 hours to extract.  is there a faster way to do this?

This is the command I use:

```
lz4 -d /mnt/tmp/7TBFile.lz4 | tar -xvf -
```

Comment: Maybe you should try `lz4 -dc /mnt/tmp/7TBFile.lz4 | tar -xvf -`. The command you use only decompress the file .

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24063846/how-to-use-tar-with-lz4  You may get a performance boost by avoiding pipes and letting tar handle lz4 . . . or you may not (depends on how tar handles the ipc)

Comment: @BrandonXavier, about pipes: check this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/361906/101265 Actually pipe make the things run in parallel (and speedup the process).